# can not use my own library typescript after build with parcel js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, parceljs

I have tried build my own lib to use on my Vue project typescript, but I can't import the lib after install them via `npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:companyName/internal-lib.git#master`

here is my `internal-lib` package.json

```
{
  "name": "@companyName/internal-lib",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "css": "dist/style.css",
  "module": "dist/module.js",
  "types": "dist/types.d.ts",
  "targets": {
    "main": {
      "source": "src/main.ts"
    },
    "css": {
      "source": "src/style.css"
    }
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc": "^2.8.3",
    "parcel": "^2.8.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

and here is my `src/main.ts`

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

class UtilDatetime {
    /**
     *
     * @param date {string}
     * @param format { string}
     * @return {*|string}
     */
    static formatDate(date: string, format = 'DD MMMM YYYY, HH:mm Z'): string {
        return date ? dayjs(date).format(format) : '-'
    }
}

export { UtilDatetime }
```

parcel js doesn't build `dist/types.d.ts` here, I don't know why

I build them via `parcel build`, then after I install that lib above and import into my Vue project

```
import UtilDateTime from '@companyName/internal-lib'
```

my IDE said

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@companyName/internal-lib'. '/Users/myNameHere/Documents/contribute/companyName/fe/cms-thing/node_modules/@companyName/internal-lib/dist/main.js'

implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/companyName__internal-lib`
if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@companyName/internal-lib';`
```

but when I import like this

```
import { UtilDatetime } from '@companyName/internal-lib/src/main'
```

is that something wrong when I build the library?

why  I can't import only from `@companyName/internal-lib` instead I need to import full path ?

Answer (score 0):

How does your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Does it have the `declaration` option? And set to `true`?

If that's not the case, you should add it.

Here's more information about the declaration option:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration